# Download file directly to memory

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, farpoint-spread

I would like to load an excel file directly from an ftp site into a memory stream. Then I want to open the file in the FarPoint Spread control using the OpenExcel(Stream) method.  My issue is I'm not sure if it's possible to download a file directly into memory.  Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Yes; just use streams.

Comment: Okay, so I can load the file from ftp web address link directly into a stream instance? Or would I need to download the file to the user's machine first? I'd prefer the former if it's possible.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, you can download a file from FTP to memory.

I think you can even pass the Stream from the FTP server to be processed by FarPoint.

```
WebRequest request = FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://asd.com/file");

using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    OpenExcel(responseStream);
}
```

Using WebClient you can do nearly the same. Generally using WebClient is easier but gives you less configuration options and control (eg.: No timeout setting).

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData("ftp://asd.com/file")))
{
    OpenExcel(stream);
}
```

Comment: Are we certain `WebResponse.GetResponseStream` doesn't shove the data into a temp file and return a `FileStream` or something similar?

Comment: It doesn't even start downloading anything until you start reading the stream. I am sure about this, since if you don't continue reading for a while the servers going to timeout. see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.getresponsestream(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 25):

Take a look at [WebClient.DownloadData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f.aspx). You should be able to download the file directory to memory and not write it to a file first.

This is untested, but something like:

```
var spreadSheetStream
    = new MemoryStream(new WebClient().DownloadData(yourFilePath));
```

I'm not familiar with FarPoint though, to say whether or not the stream can be used directly with the `OpenExcel` method. [Online examples](http://www.clubfarpoint.com/FarPointSupportSite/Modules/Docs/SpreadWeb4Help/FarPoint.Web.Spread~FarPoint.Web.Spread.FpSpread~OpenExcel(Stream).html) show the method being used with a `FileStream`, but I'd assume any kind of `Stream` would be accepted.

Comment: Found this useful for me. I was trying to download a .zip file from a website but was using new WebClient().OpenRead(file) to get the stream but getting a "stream does not support seek operation" errors. Dunno why this one worked but I appreciate it :)

Comment: I used it and it works well I'm saving file to memory and download it for Client in browser
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var pdf = new MemoryStream(new WebClient().DownloadData($"http://localhost:56110/Upload/{item.PDF}")).ToArray();
string fileName = item.Title + Path.GetExtension(item.PDF);
return File(pdf, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, fileName);

Answer (score 1):

Download file from URL to memory.
*My answer does not exactly show, how to download a file for use in Excel, but shows how to create a generic-purpose in-memory byte array.*

```
    private static byte[] DownloadFile(string url)
    {
        byte[] result = null;

        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            result = webClient.DownloadData(url);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Where is it? I can't see it! I rewrite this code to use in my project. So somene will need it.

Comment: they are not complete&ready to use code snippets for begginer levels.

Comment: Well, they do answer the question. What your answer actually does not. Maybe you should add some explanation text, like *"my answer does not exactly show, how to download a file for use in Excel, but shows how to create a generic-purpose in-memory byte array"*. Though in general, one should prefer using streams instead of arrays, as in most cases, you do not all data in memory at the same time.