# c# Load Image from ftp server directly into picture box without downloading

Tags: c#, ftp

I have looked every where for my answer but couldn't find the right solution.Tried many solutions provided but still can't get it through.I uploaded an image in ftp server and i want it to get displayed into picture box in windows form without downloading it into local machine. Is it possible?
Please include complete code for the solution......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DownloadData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f.aspx) to get a byte array and load that into the picturebox - see [Download file directly to memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686599/download-file-directly-to-memory) and [How to put image in a picture box from a byte[] in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576868/how-to-put-image-in-a-picture-box-from-a-byte-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Using direct file path to the server gives error......... file not accessible... it might be because no credentials were supplied...... so how would i supply authenticate to the server before downloading data

Comment: client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");

Comment: Sorry to say but its not helping me out...... will it be possible if u could post a complete code regarding this specific problem......

Comment: the path u showed me is apparently doing something..... the code is working i guess... but the problem is the image that is being displayed is just a blue image nothing else.... still unable to figure it out please help!! @NDJ

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Sorry couldnt answer comments, was asleep :) feel free to accept answer if it helped you to get to solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete code: If any body needs.Make sure the image isn't large!!

```
public byte [] GetImgByte (string ftpFilePath)
{
    WebClient ftpClient = new WebClient();
    ftpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername,ftpPassword);

    byte[] imageByte = ftpClient.DownloadData(ftpFilePath);
    return imageByte;
}

public static Bitmap ByteToImage(byte[] blob)
{
    MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
    byte[] pData = blob;
    mStream.Write(pData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(pData.Length));
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream, false);
    mStream.Dispose();
    return bm;
}
```